# printing the number of times a element occurs in a file using regex

Tags: regex, awk

I have a long data similar to below

```
    16:24:59        0       0       0
    16:24:59        0       1       0
    16:25:00        0       1       0
    16:25:00        0       1       0
    16:25:00        0       2       0
    16:25:00        0       2       0
    16:25:00        1       0       1
    16:25:01        0       0       0
    16:25:01        0       0       0
    16:25:01        0       0       0
    16:25:01        0       0       0
    16:25:01        4       9       4
    16:25:02        0       0       0
    16:25:02        0       0       0
    16:25:02        0       0       0
    16:25:02        0       1       0
    16:25:02        1       9       1
    16:25:02        2       0       2
```

I wish to have a output where it prints the element in column 1, and the number of times it occurs. Below is what I expect. How can I do this?

```
    16:24:59        2
    16:25:00        5
    16:25:01        5
    16:25:02        6
```

How can I replace the above to

```
    t1        2
    t2        5
    t3        5
    t4        6
     .
     .
    tn        9
```

Comment: Is that tab delimited or space delimited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward using `awk`

```
awk '{count[$1]++} END{ for ( i in count) print i, count[i]}'
```

**Test**

```
$ awk '{count[$1]++} END{ for ( i in count) print i, count[i]}' input
16:24:59 2
16:25:00 5
16:25:01 5
16:25:02 6
```

**What it does?**

- `count[$1]++` creates an associative array indexed by the first field.
- `END` Action performed at the end of input file.
- `for ( i in count) print i, count[i]` Iterate through the array `count` and print the values

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you want a grep and uniq solution:

```
$ grep -Eo '^\s*\d\d:\d\d:\d\d' /tmp/lines.txt | uniq -c
   2     16:24:59
   5     16:25:00
   5     16:25:01
   6     16:25:02
```

Or, if tab delimited, use `cut`:

```
$ cut -f 2 /tmp/lines.txt | uniq -c
   2 16:24:59
   5 16:25:00
   5 16:25:01
   6 16:25:02
```